# Is Clojure compiled or interpreted?

Tags: clojure, compilation, jvm-languages, interpreted-language, compiled-language

I read somewhere Clojure is compiled. Is it really compiled, like Java or Scala, rather than interpreted, like Jython or JRuby?

Comment: @Marcin I did but it confuses me a bit. Could you provide an aswer along with the donwvote?

Comment: "Clojure is a compiled language - it compiles directly to JVM bytecode, yet remains completely dynamic." Clear enough?

Comment: Actually that paragraph was the one that brings me here in first place.

Comment: Then I don't see why you are confused. Clojure is strictly a compiled language, just like Java and Scala. The difference with Java is that it can also compile code at run-time and load it, instead of relying on a distinct compilation phase.

Comment: I'm not sure how much clearer that could be.

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519384/editing-programs-while-they-are-running-how

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Clojure is **always compiled**.

The Clojure compiler produces Java byte code, which is typically then JIT-compiled to native code by the JVM.

The thing that can be confusing is the dynamic and interactive nature of Clojure that means you can invoke the compiler at run-time if you want to. This is all part of the Lisp "code is data" tradition.

For example, the following will invoke the Clojure compiler at run-time to compile and execute the form `(+ 1 2)`:

```
(eval '(+ 1 2))
=> 3
```

The ability to invoke the compiler at run-time is very useful - for example it enables you to compile and run new code in the middle of a running Clojure application by using the REPL. But it's important not to confuse this "interactive" style of development with being "interpreted" - Clojure development is interactive, but still always compiled.

Answer (score 19):

Both-ish! (when it comes to generating bytecode)

Clojure is on-the-fly-**[compiled at code load time](http://clojure.org/evaluation)** into JVM bytecode, which has the feeling and flow of an interpreted language, and **[ahead-of-time compiled](http://clojure.org/compilation)** into JVM bytecode, which has the flow of a compiled language. **both of these are then JIT compiled** into machine code by the Java Hotspot compiler which takes care of the dynamic optimization that Clojure depends on for speed. just to make things interesting "loaded/evaluated" code can compile on the fly at runtime, and AOT compiled code can load and evaluate source at runtime.

- If you want "interpreted" then you can `(load "/my/file.clj")` from the repl.
- If you want Ahead-Of-Time compiling, may I suggest using the [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) clojure project management tool.

In this case when i mention compiling vs. interpreting I should be clear that I am talking about **turning source code into JVM bytecode.** All JVM languages are [compiled by the JVM at runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) so that distinction is not really very interesting.

Comment: Both! is wrong its only the flow of an interpreted language there is never anything interpreted.

Comment: we are running into the contention between pure deffinitions and clear concise answers. in the last paragraph. I am talking about the process of creating JVM bytecode.

Answer (score 5):

Clojure is a compiled JVM language. That means that the first step it takes when confronted with a new program is to compile it to JVM bytecode.

Some of the JVM bytecode may later be compiled to machine code by HotSpot, if you're using OpenJDK or a derivative of it.

As a high-level language, Clojure has a form of dynamic typing, which is what the "completely dynamic" phrase is referring to.